# Using intended data in card view

Tags: java, listview, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

How would I put the variable word as the title in the get horizontal data function. I know that one has to be static and the other can't, I'm just asking how would I put a variable that I've passed to this activity in a cardview because that is essentially what I'm trying to do.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //DETERMINE WHO STARTED THIS ACTIVITY
    final String sender = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getIntent().getExtras()).getString("SENDER_KEY");

    //IF ITS THE FRAGMENT THEN RECEIVE DATA
    if(sender != null)
    {
        this.receiveData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

public void receiveData() {
    //RECEIVE DATA VIA INTENT
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String word = i.getStringExtra("NAME_KEY");

    //SET DATA TO TEXTVIEWS
    tv.setText(word);
}

private ArrayList<Object> getObject() {
    objects.add(getHorizontalData().get(0));
    objects.add(getVerticalData().get(0));
    return objects;
}

public static ArrayList<SingleHorizontal> getHorizontalData() {
    ArrayList<SingleHorizontal> singleHorizontals = new ArrayList<>();
    //String word = "yo";
    singleHorizontals.add(new SingleHorizontal(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "I want word to be right here", "Sir Charles Spencer \"Charlie\" Chaplin, KBE was an English comic actor,....", "2010/2/1"));
    singleHorizontals.add(new SingleHorizontal(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Mr.Bean", "Mr. Bean is a British sitcom created by Rowan Atkinson and Richard Curtis, and starring Atkinson as the title character.", "2010/2/1"));
    singleHorizontals.add(new SingleHorizontal(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Jim Carrey", "James Eugene \"Jim\" Carrey is a Canadian-American actor, comedian, impressionist, screenwriter...", "2010/2/1"));
    return singleHorizontals;
}

public static ArrayList<SingleVertical> getVerticalData() {
    ArrayList<SingleVertical> singleVerticals = new ArrayList<>();
    singleVerticals.add(new SingleVertical("Charlie Chaplin", "Sir Charles Spencer \"Charlie\" Chaplin, KBE was an English comic actor,....", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    singleVerticals.add(new SingleVertical("Mr.Bean", "Mr. Bean is a British sitcom created by Rowan Atkinson and Richard Curtis, and starring Atkinson as the title character.", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    singleVerticals.add(new SingleVertical("Jim Carrey", "James Eugene \"Jim\" Carrey is a Canadian-American actor, comedian, impressionist, screenwriter...", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    singleVerticals.add(new SingleVertical("Jim Carrey", "James Eugene \"Jim\" Carrey is a Canadian-American actor, comedian, impressionist, screenwriter...", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    singleVerticals.add(new SingleVertical("anotha one", "James Eugene \"Jim\" Carrey is a Canadian-American actor, comedian, impressionist, screenwriter...", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    return singleVerticals;
}
```

I passed data from a fragment to this activity. If anyone wants the Verticaladapter code or the singlevertical class just reply.